# Move files from folder to new folder based on # of files

Tags: batch-file, automation, directory

This may be a specific case but given the right code I'm sure many could take from it.

I have thousands of files in one folder that need to be split up into multiple folders. Each folder needs to have 1 more file than the one before it and needs to be named as such. Each folder needs to have at least `X` amount of files. For example, here is what the end results might look like if each folder had to have at least 1 file:

```
U:\Batch\Original\ -->
    file1.xml
    file2.xml
    file3.xml
    file4.xml
    file5.xml
    file6.xml

U:\Batch\Processed\ -->
    folder1.1 -->
        file1.xml
    folder2.2 -->
        file2.xml
        file3.xml
    folder3.3 -->
        file4.xml
        file5.xml
        file6.xml
```

I have started [attempting this on my own](http://pastebin.com/LZwDgUB4) but I feel I am way off. Say I needed at least 1000 files in each folder. How would one go about doing this in a `.bat` program?

Comment: i know this does not lead to an answer given your `.bat` stipulated limitation but `Perl` is a great tool to do these kind of things should you find yourself more in this position of needing to do them more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.  This should handle it.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a "minimum=1000, outer=minimum, inner=1"
set folder_prefix=folder
call :mkfolder

:: dir list, order by name, exclude directories, exclude this batch script
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /o:n /a:-d ^| findstr /v "%~nx0"') do (
    if !inner! GTR !outer! (
        set /a "inner=1, outer+=1"
        call :mkfolder
    )
    copy "%%I" "!folder!" >NUL
    set /a "inner+=1"
)

:: rename final directory to reflect the number of files contained within
for /f "delims=" %%I in ("%folder%") do set "to=%%~dpnI"
set /a "inner-=1"
ren "%folder%" "%to%.%inner%"


goto :EOF

:mkfolder
set folder=%folder_prefix%!outer!.!outer!
if not exist "!folder!" mkdir "!folder!"
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Since the number of files in the folder needs to be part of the folder name (i.e., after the `.`), the number of files in the last folder will likely not match the value after the `.` in the folder name.

Comment: @JamesL. - OK, it renames the final directory to reflect the number of files it contains now.

Comment: @rojo Great! I have one caveat; let's say I need to **copy** them into a different directory instead of **rewriting** the same directory?

Comment: @rojo Yes. I assume rename `move` to `copy` however I'm not familiar with the way you wrote this. ;)

Comment: @Shaz - OK I changed "move" to "copy" for you.

Comment: @rojo This worked! Anyway to make this faster? By which I mean it's using very little of the cpu/memory and taking a little while to process. ;)

Comment: Not really, not without switching to another language.  Windows batch `for` loops are pretty slow.  vbscript or jscript might be faster.  Of course, most of the time is probably being spent performing the actual copying -- so in that regard, rewriting in a different language might not cause as dramatic an improvement as you might hope.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.  To demonstrate, first we need to create a few files to work with:

```
md c:\y
cd /d c:\y
for %i in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30) do echo.>%i.txt
```

Now we can run the following batch file from `c:\y` to create sub folders and copy the files as you indicated (but with 3 as the minimum files in this example):

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set cnt=1
set fldr=1
set min=3

for %%i in (*.txt) do (
  if !cnt! GTR !min! (
    set /a cnt-=1
    ren folder!fldr! folder!fldr!.!cnt!
    set cnt=1
    set /a fldr+=1
    set /a min+=1
  )

  md folder!fldr! > nul 2>&1

  copy "%%i" folder!fldr!

  set /a cnt+=1
)

set /a cnt-=1
ren folder!fldr! folder!fldr!.!cnt!
```

Comment: I appreciate the help! With your first code block is this supposed to be creating the files? It creates the directory but not the files themselves. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: The first code block is just to create 30 files so I could create a test case to demonstrate that the batch file (2nd code block) works.  You only need the 2nd code block.  Change `min` to `1000` and `(*.txt)` to `(*.xml)`.

Comment: If you want to **move** the files instead of **copy** them, just change the `copy` command to `move` in the 2nd code block.

Comment: It seems like I've encountered situations in the past where `for var in (mask)` processes items in an order other than alphabetical.  I feel safer parsing `dir /o` to assert the order I want where order matters.

Comment: To create some test files you can use `for /l %i in (1,1,20000) do @echo %i> %i.txt`:)